# How to retrieve columns with criteria for the latest date in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the original dataframe.

```
      Country     Date     Confirmed    Death   Recovered   newConfirmed    newDeath    newRecovered
No                              
1   Afghanistan 31/12/2019     0          0         0            0              0           0
2   Afghanistan 01/01/2020     0          0         0            0              0           0
3   Afghanistan 02/01/2020     0          0         0            0              0           0
4   Afghanistan 03/01/2020     0          0         0            0              0           0
5   Afghanistan 20/03/2020     0          0         0            0              0           0
```

I want to retrieve only  Columns 'Country', 'Confirmed', 'Death', and 'Recovered' for the date '2020-03-20'(which is the latest date)  from the original DataFrame into a new DataFrame.

How should I do this?

Comment: @jezrael i've worked on this but it doesnt give me the required answer.

Comment: @jezrael No, actually the max date is fixed on 20/03/2020 but there are more than one data with this date. Therefore it is not only the last row.

Comment: The question requires me to show Columns 'Country', 'Confirmed', 'Death', and 'Recovered' for the Max Date only.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks this works for geting the latest date but I also need to filter the Columns 'Country', 'Confirmed', 'Death', and 'Recovered'.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks a bundle!!

Comment: Answer is correct, I forget for `dayfirst=True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) witth max values, but first is necessary convert strings to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `dayfirst=True` parameter:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True) 
df1 = df.loc[df['Date'].eq(df['Date'].max()), ['Country', 'Confirmed', 'Death', 'Recovered']]
print (df1)
       Country  Confirmed  Death  Recovered
5  Afghanistan          0      0          0
```